# In VS Code, when using CMake to generate Makefiles, do I need the Makefile Tools extension if I have the CMake Tools extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, makefile

Do I still need to use the makefile tool after using the cmake tool in vscode?
When using stm32cubemx to automatically generate a project, the makefile file will be generated in the root directory.

I have tried to use makefile tools directly in vscode, but I feel that the configuration is very messy. Does the makefile tool automatically configure cmake tools? Cube is a directly and automatically generated makeflie. I know the relationship between cmakelist and makefile very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For practical purposes, no. If you're using CMake to generate Makefiles, you don't need Makefile Tools. CMake Tools should be sufficient.

If you already have a Makefile through other means, unless some other part of your build requires CMake (such a dependency that uses CMake), there's no need to involve CMake at all.

Comment: What bothers me is that when vscode launches the c/c++ plug-in, it will automatically download cmake tools, while cube automatically generates a makefile instead of cmakelist. Will cmake tools automatically generate a cmakelist file based on the makefile? Currently, vscode has makefile tools to automatically generate makefile files. Searching in the project root directory, it seems that there is no need to use cmake tools at this time.

Comment: as far as I know, VS Code does not automatically download CMake Tools when activating the C/C++ extension. Nor does it install extensions without prompting you for permission. The rest of what you're saying totally confuses me. CMake can generate Makefiles from CMake configurations- not the other way around. That just makes no sense. If you already have a Makefile through other means, you don't need to involve CMake at all.